# Inexplicable bad estimation in a Poisson regression (GLMM)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, survival, poisson-regression

I need to use a Poisson regression to obtain the equivalent of a piecewise exponential estimation for the survival curve. So far so good.

The problem occurs when I add a covariate to my time variable.
Roughly, my model looks like this : $log(\mu_j) = D_k * Z + b_{0_{j}} + b_{1_{j}} * Z + log(\gamma_j)$ with $D_k$ the time cutted in $k$ intervals, $log(\gamma_j)$ the offset, $log(\mu_j)$ the equivalent of the event indicator and the $b's$ two random effects.

I used the `glmer` function from the `lme4` package (and `glm` to be sure that it was not a problem with `glmer`) and I compared the obtained estimations graphically with those obtained with `Survfit`. As long as, I don't add a covariate on the time variable ($D_k$) everything is good; but when I add this stratitification term, the `glmer` (or equivalently `glm`) estimation for the survival does not work at all.

I dont undestand at all what's happening here. 
I tried the function on real and simulated data set but the results were always the same. I also changed the number of intervals for the time variable (10,20,30) without any success.

Has anyone a clue that would help me to solve this this problem that I've been blocking for weeks ?
 [image]
Below is an example on a simulated dataset:

```
library(lme4)
library(survival)
library(surrosurv)

id = seq(1,1000, 1)
Z = rbinom (1000, 1, 0.5)
surv = rexp(1000, rate = 1*exp(Z))
cens = rexp(1000, 0.5)
time = pmin(surv, cens)
status = ifelse(cens > surv, 1 , 0)
J = rbinom(1000, 3, 0.5)
data = data.frame(cbind(id, Z,time, status, J))
data = subset(data, data$time < 1)

# Poissonization
interval.width = 0.05
don_pois = poissonize(data, interval.width = interval.width, factors = c ('Z', 'J'), compress = FALSE)

fitpoi_glmer   <- glmer(
  formula = event ~ -1 + interval * Z + offset(log(time)) + ( 1 + Z | J ),
  data = don_pois,
  family = poisson(link = "log")
                       )
# Graphical comparison

fixed.coef.glmer = summary(fitpoi_glmer)$coefficients[,'Estimate'] 

# Hazards and survival times in the group  0 and 1
risks0 = exp(fixed.coef.glmer[grep("(?!.*:)interval.*", names(fixed.coef.glmer), perl = T)]) * 0.1
surv0  = c(1,exp(-cumsum(risks0)))
x      = seq(0, 1, interval.width)[-(length(surv0)+1)]
risks1 = exp(fixed.coef.glmer[grep("(?!.*:)interval.*", names(fixed.coef.glmer), perl = T)]+fixed.coef.glmer[grep("Z", names(fixed.coef.glmer), perl = T)]) * 0.1
surv1 <- c(1,exp(-cumsum(risks1)))

plot(x, surv0, type ='l', col = 'blue', lwd = 2, ylim = 0:1, ylab = 'Survival', xlab = 'Times',
     main = "Survival estimations stratified on Z")
lines(x, surv1, type ='l', col = 'red', lwd = 2)

# Comparison with survfit
lines(survfit(Surv(time, status)~1+strata(Z), data = data  ), lty = 1:2, lwd =2, conf.int= FALSE)

legend(legend =c("glmer  0","glmer 1", "Survfit 0","Survfit 1" ), 
       col = c('blue', 'red',  'black', 'black'),
       lty = c(rep(1,3),2), 
       lwd = 2,'bottomleft')
```

Comment: What makes you think the two modelling approaches should produce comparable results?

Comment: You should use ":" instead of "*" in glmer for the interaction between "interval" and "Z". Maybe you should use "factor(Z)" instead of "Z"

Comment: @winperikle it seems working ! I thank you a lot :-) Would you mind to explain to me what was the problem in my formulation ? Also, if you want to add an answer, I will accept it with pleasure

Comment: Using * will add main effects and interactions terms in the formula. If you want separate baseline risks for each strata (i.e. a stratification) you shouln't include the main effects for the stratification variables and for the intervals variables. Using colon will only include interaction terms. Another way is to use * and remove the main effects by adding "-factor(Z)" and "-factor(interval)" in the formula which should give the same results as : alone. Note that the risks for each strate could be computed from main and interaction term but this require calculations between estimations

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Your comments were so helpful for me :-)